# XFC0040 Cannot convert value "X Y" to "Xamarin.Forms.Thickness"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

У мня есть такая строка:

```
<Entry x:Name="volumeEntry" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="50 5" Keyboard="Telephone"/>
```

Несколько часов всё работало нормально, но внезапно при сборке стала появляться ошибка XFC0040. Я нагуглил, что это вроде как баг xamarin`а, чтобы обойти который нужно добавить запятые между параметрами Margin:

```
<Entry x:Name="volumeEntry" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="50, 5" Keyboard="Telephone"/>
```

Теперь приложение собирается, но все текстбоксы, в параметрах которых поставлены запятые просто не отображается на экране, как будто они скрыты. Если во время отладки со включенным Hot Reload убрать запятые, то элементы сразу появляются, но при следующей сборке опять ошибка. Перезапуск студии, очистка и пересборка проекта не помогают.

Как сделать так, чтобы и не вызывать ошибку XFC0040, и чтобы элементы отображались?

Comment: А если поставить значение поменьше? Допустим `5, 5`?

Comment: Даже нули пробовал, всё без толку

Comment: Что интересно, Label (который тоже выдавал эту ошибку) с запятыми в параметрах отображается, а Entry - нет. Как включить принудительное отображение для элемента (если это возможно)? Может поможет.

Comment: Попробовал подставить разные значения. Вы правы, на некотором диапазоне меньших значений элемент начинает отображаться. Хотя такого же размера, какого он был без запятой в параметрах, добиться не получается. Странно и глупо получилось. Вопрос можно закрывать, спасибо.

Comment: Мой вам совет, не используйте `Margin` для позиционирования объектов, он не предназначен для этого, ведь это просто отступ, который должен быть не более, не знаю 10-20 пунктов. Для позиционирования есть сетка, есть свойства ориентации (верх, низ, лево, право), есть всякие панели компоновки объектов и далее, далее, далее. Сам же `Margin` (отступ) - это когда вот у вас стоят рядом два объекта, а вы хотите, чтоб между ними был небольшой отступ, чтоб не сливались друг с другом, вот тогда и используете это значение. Просто возьмите за правило, если вы пишете `Margin = 50`, то значит гдет косяк.

Comment: Я использую grid, просто хотел сделать entry поменьше, чтобы он не растягивался на всю ячейку. Привык к удобному графическому конструктору в WPF, а тут его нет, приходится привыкать делать всё вручную, подтупливаю.

Comment: Ну так разместите его, например по центру и задайте `Padding` или что-то еще, чтоб был нужного вида. Также сам `Grid` можете настроить, чтоб ячейка нужная была поменьше, `Grid` в `Grid` в конце концов) Вариантов куча на самом деле) `Привык к удобному графическому конструктору в WPF` - в котором вы мышью все двигаете, и он вам ставит `Margin = "532, 234, 643, 242"`?) Ну такое...) От такого наоборот бежать надо. Я вон в WPF запускаю проект и руками пишу XAML, видя как в живую, на моем проекте все выглядит, советую!)

Comment: Так и буду теперь, просто привычку ломать больно)

Answer (score 1):

Элемент скрывался из-за слишком большого значения Margin. Нужно использовать меньшие значения. Что касается ошибки, то вероятно это баг. Для предотвращения ошибки всегда ставьте запятые между параметрами Margin и аккуратнее подбирайте значения этих параметров во избежание "схлопывания" элемента.

Comment: Действительно, компилятор xaml ждёт запятые. 
Хотя при редактировании на лету, компилятор нормально подхватывает значения и без запятых.